# Is $f_{XY}(x,y)$ the same as $f(x,y)$?

Tags: density-function

I have a slight confusion with the notation, sometimes I find the joint density function like this:
$$f_{XY}(x,y)$$
and on other occasions like this:
$$f(x,y)$$
Is the same or what is the difference?
Thanks!

Comment: So it would seem, consistently with the habit of indicating with $f_S$ the pdf of the random variable $S$. However, one might contend that $f_{X,Y}$ is more accurate, because $f_{XY}$ should be used for the pdf of the random variable $XY$, rather than for the pdf of the random vector $(X,Y)$. Notice that this ambiguity can be solved by observing that the pdf of $XY$ is a map $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, while the pdf of $(X,Y)$ is a map $\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of $f_{XY}(x,y)$, you are specifying that the random variables you are taking the joint density of are $X$ and $Y$.  If you just write $f(x,y)$, you had better be stating somewhere which random variables this joint density belongs to.